# Http request: How can I get a value inside curly braces

Tags: java, android, http, kotlin, retrofit2

I try to make a Weather App. And when I try to for example: Get timezone(which is outside the curly braces) it works, but when I try to get the temperature it doesn't.
Here is where I want it from
[image]
And this is my Class

```
data class WeatherClass (
    //here I don't know how to get the temp
    @field:Json(name = "main")
    val temp: Double,
    val timezone: Int,
    val id: Int
)
```

Comment: just convert the json data into java object(s)

Comment: Please don't paste text as an image into a question. Here's why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Ok, i will remember for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a nested `Json`, you cannot directly access `temp` using `main`, create a `Main` class and add `temp` inside it

```
data class Main(val temp: Double)
```

Then add `Main` inside `WeatherClass`

```
 data class WeatherClass (
      val main: Main,
      val timezone: Int,
      val id: Int){

      val temp:Double
          get() = main.temp
  }
```